# Else is simply skipped, but only sometimes

Tags: java, if-statement

```
private int bkicalc(int i, List<Integer> history) {

    List<Integer> subList = history.subList(history.size()-1 - i, history.size()-1);
    Set<Integer> uniliste = new HashSet<Integer>(subList);
    
    if (uniliste.size() == 4) {
        if (i>5) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        return i;
    } else {
        this.bkicalc(i + 1, history);
    }
    
       System.out.println("else was skipped");
    return 404;

}
```

Hi, this method is accessed a 1000 times from a for-loop, and in 1/10 of times it skips the else and returns the 404. I cannot explain to myself why this is happening.

Hope you can help me out.

Comment: why do you recursively call a method, but use the return value only sometimes?

Comment: The problem seems to be that a certain point you just unroll the stack when the recursion is over and the last call to `bkicalc` simply terminates its `else` clause and just return the 404 after the `if/else`. So just like juwil's comment implies you should return from the `else` as well.

Comment: The idea was to repeat the method as long as the hashset has 4 different elements in order to skip the duplicates in history and get the offset to the 4th different element. The Else should just repeat the method, do you have a idea what return statement I have to add to the else to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return from the `if` branch, but not from the `else` branch.  Therefore, the diagnostic and 404 return do not indicate that the `else` was skipped, but rather that it was *taken*.  That the `else` branch recurses is irrelevant: unless an exception is thrown from the recursive invocation, that invocation will eventually return, at which point control simply passes out of the `else` block.

It looks like you probably want in the `else` branch to return the result of the recursive invocation:

```
private int bkicalc(int i, List<Integer> history) {

    List<Integer> subList = history.subList(history.size()-1 - i, history.size()-1);
    Set<Integer> uniliste = new HashSet<Integer>(subList);
    
    if (uniliste.size() == 4) {
        if (i>5) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        return i;
    } else {
        return this.bkicalc(i + 1, history);  // <-- here
    }
    
    assert false : "unreachable";
    return 404;
}
```

You might even find with that that the compiler actually flags the `return 404` as unreachable.

Note also that the bounds on your sublist are a bit surprising.  The upper bound provided to `List.subList()` is *exclusive*, not inclusive, so you are consistently omitting the the last element of `history` from consideration.  If that's intentional then it would be wise to add a code comment saying so.

Furthermore, if `history` does not in fact contain at least 4 distinct elements overall, then after some number of recursions, this method will fail with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  This is of course certain to happen if it does not initially contain at least 5 elements total (remembering that one is ignored).

Finally, the recursion seems wasteful and unnecessarily confusing.  An iterative approach would be better, for a variety of reasons.  (It almost always is.) Example:

```
private int bkicalc(int i, List<Integer> history) {
    if (history.size() >= 5) {
        Set<Integer> uniliste = new HashSet<Integer>(
                history.subList(history.size() - 5, history.size() - 1));
        ListIterator<Integer> iterator = history.listIterator(history.size() - 5);

        while (uniliste.size() < 4 && iterator.hasPrevious()) {
            uniliste.add(iterator.previous());
        }

        if (uniliste.size() == 4) {
            int i = history.size() - 1 - iterator.nextIndex();

            if (i > 5) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            return i;
        }
    }

    // Fewer than 4 distinct elements (ignoring the last)
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very mu h, now it works. You are right, I didnt know the bound is exclusive, that was not intentional. The history list has always 20 elements in it, that was the first mistake I corrected that after the out of bounds exception. Unfortunately I dont get why the return is neccessary, because I thought the values of the Recursed method are given with the parameters

Comment: Youre great thank you very much. Your iterative approach is a lot better than my recursive one.